# Deciphering the following method

Tags: recursion, recursive-backtracking

I'm solving a test that was given in my course about 2 years ago,and it got the following method

```
public static void what(int n,int k,String s){
          if(k==0)
              System.out.println(s);
          else if(n>0){
              what(n-1,k,s);
              what(n-1,k-1,n+s);
          }
      }
```

now,I ran it on my IDE and figured out it prints all possible combinations of k cells with n numbers.
I've took my time to follow it with the debugger as well
but I just couln't understand what's the logic behinds it

I mean,as a developer how do I go about creating such a recursion.
whats the logic behind this backtrack

Answer (score 0):

**DESCRIPTION**

```
n = range of elements
k = population of each cell
s = solution so far

if the remaining population is 0
    print the solution
else
    if there are still elements available, search two cases:
        (1) Don't use **n** in the solution; recur.
        (2) Do use **n** in the solution; 
            decrease the population by 1 and recur.
```

**DEBUGGING**

A debugger is good for finding logic flow problems.  For a big picture, you sometimes need to gather more data to survey as a whole.  Stick in a couple of **print** statements to trace the logic, and let it spew lines of output at you.

For functions, I recommend a that the first statement be a **print** to display "ENTER", the function name (redundant in this case), and the arguments.  Also print at points of decision: track the recursion step as well.

**TRACE OF THIS ROUTINE**

Here is the output when I tracked the problem, indenting 2 spaces for each level of recursion:

```
   ENTER 4 3 
   RECUR without n
     ENTER 3 3 
     RECUR without n
       ENTER 2 3 
       RECUR without n
         ENTER 1 3 
         RECUR without n
           ENTER 0 3 
         RECUR using n
           ENTER 0 2 1
       RECUR using n
         ENTER 1 2 2
         RECUR without n
           ENTER 0 2 2
         RECUR using n
           ENTER 0 1 12
     RECUR using n
       ENTER 2 2 3
       RECUR without n
         ENTER 1 2 3
         RECUR without n
           ENTER 0 2 3
         RECUR using n
           ENTER 0 1 13
       RECUR using n
         ENTER 1 1 23
         RECUR without n
           ENTER 0 1 23
         RECUR using n
           ENTER 0 0 123
123
   RECUR using n
     ENTER 3 2 4
     RECUR without n
       ENTER 2 2 4
       RECUR without n
         ENTER 1 2 4
         RECUR without n
           ENTER 0 2 4
         RECUR using n
           ENTER 0 1 14
       RECUR using n
         ENTER 1 1 24
         RECUR without n
           ENTER 0 1 24
         RECUR using n
           ENTER 0 0 124
124
     RECUR using n
       ENTER 2 1 34
       RECUR without n
         ENTER 1 1 34
         RECUR without n
           ENTER 0 1 34
         RECUR using n
           ENTER 0 0 134
134
       RECUR using n
         ENTER 1 0 234
234
```